# Spring cloud and resilience4j : 504 Gateway Timeout error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I recently replaced Hystrix with resilience4j with spring cloud. Most of the unit test are working fine but now I am getting 504 gateway timeout after 1 second. Is there anyway, I can configure the timeout in the properties? So far, I have added

```
    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                        .minimumNumberOfCalls(5).failureRateThreshold(20)
                        .build())
                .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                        .build())
                .build());
    }
```

And also set the properties in application.yml file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        response-timeout: 6s
        connect-timeout: 6000
```

Is there any other timeout, I need to configure?

Is there any workaround to configure the timeoutDuration in TimeLimiterConfig? Right now, timeoutDuration is picking up the default value of 1 second. Thats I am getting a 504.

Comment: What version are you using? There was a bug where customizers weren't being applied.

Comment: Here are spring cloud dependencies 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Hoxton.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

and resilience4j
 <resilience4j.version>1.1.0</resilience4j.version>

Comment: Next time, update the question with that information where it can be formatted rather than put it in a comment.

The issue has been fixed and will be part of Hoxton.SR2 https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/3722

Comment: I am also facing this error. @TaintedPurple, did you find solution to this issue ?